# Macro for loop argument

Tags: c++, vector, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to know why passing `v.size()` to a macro argument gives me an error but if I store the value in a temporary variable and pass that instead it works;

[image]

**Here is my code :**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#define FOR(i,a,b) for(int i=a;i<=b;++i)
#define REP(i,n) FOR(i,0,n-1)

int main(){

    int n,x;
    vector<int> v;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    REP(i, n){
        scanf("%d", &x);
        printf("Size of Vector = %d\n", v.size());
        int exists = 0;
        REP(j, v.size()){
            // Loop executes even when size = 0
            if (v[j] == x){
                exists = 1;
                break;
            }
         }
        if (!exists)
            v.push_back(x);
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

However this works :

```
int size = v.size();
REP(j, size){
    if (v[j] == x){
        exists = 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your FOR macro is doing b - 1. So if b is 0, and unsigned (as v.size() is I believe) you will get a very large number instead of -1. You should use the following macros:

```
#define FOR(i,a,b) for(int i=a;i<b;++i)
#define REP(i,n) FOR(i,0,n)
```

Comment: Good job! Now it seems so obvious. Really nice question, it will be perfect for interviews.

Comment: Thank you.
Instead I just type casted it to **int**
 `#define REP(i,n) FOR(i,0,(int)n-1)`

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
 REP(j, v.size()){
```

will be interpreted as

```
for(int j=0;j<=v.size()-1;++j) {
```

vector::size() returns an unsigned integral value. If the size is zero,  `v.size()-1` makes the maximum integral value, that is, `j<=v.size()-1` is always true.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `v.size()` is unsigned. If you extend the line `REP(j, v.size()){` you'll get `for(int j=0;j<=v.size()-1;++j)`. If `v` is empty, the result of `v.size()-1` is the maximum value an unsigned var of the type of `v.size()` can hold. In `j<=v.size()-1` the variable `j` is promoted to an unsigned type. This leads to no boundary for `j` and it becomes easy to see why you get an `vector subscript out of range` error.